# Expression/Statement trees

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

**Updated Question Further Down**

I've been experimenting with expression trees in .NET 4 to generate code at runtime and I've been trying to implement the `foreach` statement by building an expression tree.

In the end, the expression should be able to generate a delegate that does this:

```
Action<IEnumerable<int>> action = source => 
{
  var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
  while(enumerator.MoveNext())
  {
    var i = enumerator.Current;
    // the body of the foreach that I don't currently have yet
  }
}
```

I've come up with the following helper method that generates a BlockExpression from an IEnumerable:

```
public static BlockExpression ForEachExpr<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string collectionName, string itemName)
{
        var item = Expression.Variable(typeof(T), itemName);

        var enumerator = Expression.Variable(typeof(IEnumerator<T>), "enumerator");

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<T>), collectionName);

        var doMoveNext = Expression.Call(enumerator, typeof(IEnumerator).GetMethod("MoveNext"));

        var assignToEnum = Expression.Assign(enumerator, Expression.Call(param, typeof(IEnumerable<T>).GetMethod("GetEnumerator")));

        var assignCurrent = Expression.Assign(item, Expression.Property(enumerator, "Current"));

        var @break = Expression.Label();

        var @foreach = Expression.Block(
            assignToEnum,
            Expression.Loop(
                Expression.IfThenElse(
                Expression.NotEqual(doMoveNext, Expression.Constant(false)),
                    assignCurrent
                , Expression.Break(@break))
            ,@break)
        );
        return @foreach;

}
```

The following code:

```
var ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var expr = ints.ForEachExpr("ints", "i");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<IEnumerable<int>>>(expr, Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<int>), "ints"));
```

Generates this expression tree:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Action`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]]>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32] $ints)
{
    .Block() {
        $enumerator = .Call $ints.GetEnumerator();
        .Loop  {
            .If (.Call $enumerator.MoveNext() != False) {
                $i = $enumerator.Current
            } .Else {
                .Break #Label1 { }
            }
        }
        .LabelTarget #Label1:
    }
}
```

This seems to be OK, but calling `Compile` on that expression results in an exception:

```
"variable 'enumerator' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1[System.Int32]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"
```

Didn't I define it here:

```
    var enumerator = Expression.Variable(typeof(IEnumerator<T>), "enumerator");
```

?

Of course, the example here is contrived and doesn't have a practical use yet, but I'm trying to get the hang of expression trees that have bodies, in order to dynamically combine them at runtime in the future.

---

**EDIT:** My initial problem was solved by Alexandra, thanks! Of course, I've run into the next problem now. I've declared a `BlockExpression` that has a variable in it. Inside that expression, I want another expression that references that variable. But I don't have an actual reference to that variable, just its name, because the expression is supplied externally.

```
var param = Expression.Variable(typeof(IEnumerable<T>), "something");

var block = Expression.Block(
                new [] { param },
                body
            );
```

The `body` variable is passed in externally and has no direct reference to `param`, but does know the name of the variable in the expression (`"something"`). It looks like this:

```
var body = Expression.Call(typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine",new[] { typeof(bool) }), 
               Expression.Equal(Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<int>), "something"), Expression.Constant(null)));
```

This is the "code" that this generates:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Action`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]]>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32] $something)
{
    .Block(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32] $something) {
        .Call System.Console.WriteLine($something== null)
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't compile. With the same error as before.

**TLDR:** How do I reference a variable by identifier in an expression tree?

Comment: I think you can't do this. Names you give to parameters within an expression tree are more like friendly names. You actually don't need them at all, you can create a parameter without a name and the system will generate something for you. But this is more for debugging purposes than for anything else.
So, you simply created two parameters with the same name, but not a parameter and a reference to it. 
I'll take your example to the DLR team and ask whether it is a bug or not that you can create two parameters with the same name like this. But I can get the answer only after the holidays.

Comment: Hm, so it's not possible to dynamically compose a delegate by adding together separate bits and pieces in an expression tree? My end goal is to generate code using an evolutionary algorithm and for that, I really would need to be able to reference variables created in an outer scope. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I dind't say that :-) Of course you can create a delegate or a static method with expression trees (I even have a blog post about that: http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2009/09/14/generating-dynamic-methods-with-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)
But you probably need to refactor this exact piece of code, so that "body" should get a real reference to "param" not just a string name.

Comment: I feared so :( My idea was to create "pre-fab" blocks that you could supply with further expressions as bodies. Like in my foreach example, where you would generate a foreach loop from a given collection, collection name and iteration variable name. You can then use that iteration variable by referencing it by string in the foreach body, but if you need the actual reference, that's gonna be harder. Do you have any suggestions on how I could set that up, or should I start a new question for that? Thanks.

Comment: You can try to send an email to dlr@microsoft.com or visit http://dlr.codeplex.com/. This way you can talk not just to me, but to the whole DLR team. 
You are certainly welcome to start a new thread here as well. But I'll need a little bit more info about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think I have a helpful metaphor for you. Treat BlockExpressions as methods. Literally. If you need a block expression with a parameter, you need to pass this parameter to it. For example, if you call a method from a method, you still need to pass a parameter from one to another, knowing "the name" of the parameter doesn't help. Same with block expressions. You always need a real reference to a parameter. But again, it's essentially the same with methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You problem is that you didn't pass parameters and variables to your block expression. You use them in the "inner" expressions, but the block expression knows nothing about them. Basically, all you need to do is to pass all your parameters and variables to a block expression.

```
        var @foreach = Expression.Block(
            new ParameterExpression[] { item, enumerator, param },
            assignToEnum,
            Expression.Loop(
                Expression.IfThenElse(
                    Expression.NotEqual(doMoveNext, Expression.Constant(false)),
                    assignCurrent,
                    Expression.Break(@break))
            , @break)
        );
```

Comment: This threw me for a loop for a little while. I think the first parameter into Block is called "Parameters" but what it should really be called is "VariableDeclarations". This was the key to solving it though thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to dispose IEnumerator in try/finally - lots of code (such as File.ReadLines()) depends on that.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this is thread necromancy, but in case other people are running into the same or similar problem:

You can try to write an ExpressionVisitor that replaces a parameter with the same name and type in the external body expression with the variable parameter you have declared when creating the block expression. That way the parameter in the body will be the same object as the parameter in the block declaration and so the LambdaExpression should compile.

Comment: That might be a useful observation, but it's won't actually help in this case (missing declaration of local variables in `Expression.Block()`).