# Foreach loop using Expression trees

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

I have seen this [Issue while building dynamic Expression Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646283/issue-while-building-dynamic-expression-tree) and  [Expression/Statement trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936525/expression-statement-trees) and since I am new to expression trees I am still struggling to understand how to achieve what I want.

A contrived object is below

```
    public class TestObject
    {
        public TestObject()
        {
            ClassList = new List<Class>();
        }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<Class> ClassList { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Class
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ClassId { get; set; }
    }
```

At run time I iterate through each of the properties and generate a Delegate which does a conversion to string of that property. I have got all that working. The issue I have to deal with now is that for the List type, I need to be able to apply a set of actions to each item in the ClassList property so I need a foreach which allows me to do that.

I currently have this

```
//type==TestObject at runtime
//propertyName == "ClassList"
   ParameterExpression recordExpression = Expression.Parameter(type, "record");

   memberExpression = MemberExpression.Property(recordExpression, propertyName);

   Type getEnumerableDelegateType =
                typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type, memberExpression.Type}); 

   var getList = Expression.Lambda(getEnumerableDelegateType, memberExpression, recordExpression);
```

GetList when compiled and invoked returns the List as expected. What I m struggling with is how to create an expression which will use the result from the lambda expression and iterate over it applying the set of actions I have already created for each Class item.

Ultimately I am looking for a lambda signature to match the **overallAction** signature below

```
   var getListFunc = new Func<TestObject, List<Class>>((TestObject obj1) => obj1.ClassList);

   Action<List<Class>> listAction = delegate(List<Class> data)
                {
                    foreach (var dataChannelWithUnitse in data)
                    {
                        //Apply generated delegate
                    }
                };

     Action<TestObject> overallAction = delegate(TestObject data)
                {
                    var x = getListFunc.Invoke(data);
                    listAction.Invoke(x as List<Class>);
                };
```

Any help is appreciated to help me understand how to do this.

I have currently got this which is exceptioning with **variable 'Input' of type 'TestObject' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined**

```
    var typeParam = Expression.Parameter(type, "Input");
    var listVariable = Expression.Variable(memberExpression.Type, "List");
    var enumerator = Expression.Variable(typeof(IEnumerator<>).MakeGenericType(dataType));


    var enumeratorType = typeof(IEnumerator<>).MakeGenericType(dataType);
    var enumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(dataType);
    var enumerableParam = Expression.Parameter(enumerableType, "ExtractedCollection");

    var getEnumeratorFunc = Expression.Call(enumerableParam, enumerableType.GetMethod("GetEnumerator"));
    var getEnumeratorLambda = Expression.Lambda(getEnumeratorFunc, enumerableParam);

    var t1 = Expression.Assign(listVariable, Expression.Invoke(getListLambda, typeParam));
    var t2 = Expression.Assign(enumerator, Expression.Invoke(getEnumeratorLambda, listVariable));


    var @break = Expression.Label();

    var funcBlock = Expression.Block(
        new ParameterExpression[] { listVariable, enumerator},

   t1,
   t2,

    Expression.Loop(
        Expression.IfThenElse(

            Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Call(enumerator,typeof(IEnumerator).GetMethod("MoveNext")),Expression.Constant(false)),
                                Expression.Invoke(enumerableExpressions[0],Expression.Property(enumerator, "Current")),

                      Expression.Break(@break))
            , @break), typeParam);



    Expression<Action<TestObject>> lm = Expression.Lambda<Action<TestObject>>(funcBlock,recordExpression);
    var d = lm.Compile(); **//this is exceptioning with " variable 'Input' of type 'TestObject' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined**
```

Comment: `List<T>` actually has a `.ForEach()` method that you could invoke. This does not generalize to any `IEnumerable`, but in this particular case it could help you simplify your code.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I got lost somewhere in the middle of your question (and if I've interpreted it incorrectly, please tell me, and I'll dive back into it), but I *think* this is what you're after:

```
public static Expression ForEach(Expression collection, ParameterExpression loopVar, Expression loopContent)
{
    var elementType = loopVar.Type;
    var enumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
    var enumeratorType = typeof(IEnumerator<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);

    var enumeratorVar = Expression.Variable(enumeratorType, "enumerator");
    var getEnumeratorCall = Expression.Call(collection, enumerableType.GetMethod("GetEnumerator"));
    var enumeratorAssign = Expression.Assign(enumeratorVar, getEnumeratorCall);

    // The MoveNext method's actually on IEnumerator, not IEnumerator<T>
    var moveNextCall = Expression.Call(enumeratorVar, typeof(IEnumerator).GetMethod("MoveNext"));

    var breakLabel = Expression.Label("LoopBreak");

    var loop = Expression.Block(new[] { enumeratorVar },
        enumeratorAssign,
        Expression.Loop(
            Expression.IfThenElse(
                Expression.Equal(moveNextCall, Expression.Constant(true)),
                Expression.Block(new[] { loopVar },
                    Expression.Assign(loopVar, Expression.Property(enumeratorVar, "Current")),
                    loopContent
                ),
                Expression.Break(breakLabel)
            ),
        breakLabel)
    );

    return loop;
}
```

To use it, you need to supply a collection to iterate over, an expression to substitute into the body of the loop, and a ParameterExpression which is used by the loop body expression, which will be assigned to the loop variable on each loop iteration.

I think sometimes examples speak louder than words...

```
var collection = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<string>), "collection");
var loopVar = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "loopVar");
var loopBody = Expression.Call(typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { typeof(string) }), loopVar);
var loop = ForEach(collection, loopVar, loopBody);
var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Action<List<string>>>(loop, collection).Compile();
compiled(new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" });
```

EDIT: As Jeroem Mostert correctly points out in the comments, this doesn't *quite* mirror the "real" behaviour of a foreach loop: this would make sure that it disposes the enumerator. (It would also create a new instance of the loop variable for each iteration, but that doesn't make sense with expressions). Implementing this is just a matter of turning the handle if you feel motivated enough!

---

For anyone watching at home, I've got a similar method for generating 'for' loops:

```
public static Expression For(ParameterExpression loopVar, Expression initValue, Expression condition, Expression increment, Expression loopContent)
{
    var initAssign = Expression.Assign(loopVar, initValue);

    var breakLabel = Expression.Label("LoopBreak");

    var loop = Expression.Block(new[] { loopVar },
        initAssign,
        Expression.Loop(
            Expression.IfThenElse(
                condition,
                Expression.Block(
                    loopContent,
                    increment
                ),
                Expression.Break(breakLabel)
            ),
        breakLabel)
    );

    return loop;
}
```

This is equivalent to the following statement, where the pseudo-variables match the Expressions in the method above:

```
for (loopVar = initValue; condition; increment)
{
    loopContent
}
```

Again, loopContent, condition, and increment are Expressions which uses loopVar, and loopVar is assigned on every iteration.

Comment: This is almost but not quite like the real `foreach`: `IEnumerator<T>` is disposable, and an actual `foreach` will dispose it. Of course, the vast majority of enumerators have do-nothing implementations (including all those of the standard collection classes) and this will generally work fine. The full semantics of `foreach` are actually pretty complicated because no interfaces are necessary at all (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754 is out of date but the language spec gives the nitty-gritty); I don't necessarily recommend implementing that except as a challenge. :-)

Comment: That's a good point, and there's a try/finally around that Dispose operation as well, if I remember correctly! I'll add a note to this effect in my answer

Comment: Thank you all very much, was moved onto something else, just got back to it and it works perfectly! @canton7

Answer (score 7):

[relatively_random's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52762241/861773) is great but `foreach` handles several other scenarios. Check these links to SharpLab to verify what is generated in each of them:

- When the [enumerable is a `IEnumerable<T>`](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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), it checks if the enumerator is `null` before calling `Dispose()`.
- When the [enumerable is not an interface](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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), the enumerator changes to have the type returned by `GetEnumerator()`. The enumerator is cast to `IDisposable` before calling `Dispose()`.
- When the [enumerator doesn't implement `IDisposable`](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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), `as` is used on the check if the enumerator implements `IDisposable`. (???)
- When the [enumerator is a value type](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMDcCwAocVoDoDCB7ANjgpgMYAuAllgHYDOCykMALLUiAMyoBsUATKgOwQkAbyQQxUdjC4gGEALIBDUhQAUASkGJxEEVu3iAZlgBO+BYQAWKgG4LjEWzgCu+CMogAVfFWIBRCk4AtvjGCgBGBGgASgoUAOb4KtBgamqi+mIAkDAAnDYKzvhqtNoAvkjliCyS0NK8Xj7+QSHhBMLpYmycEE3BoRGuMfGJysQQhFhOFMQaHfoAvAB8EBT4AO49AX2tiRNTM8x6nZK8vS0DEABcqKwAPKOLc7oZYqYKACaUOACebtPjk2mhxeEk2zX6BBUowB+zSR30zxB4mIFlIVDQe3+8xhQLmZSQePEXTOoWIJggAHF8H4ti0ycZ1BAlit1mDtvSVJiDoSxABJEkKen3abLGB3B5oKk08GCkyM5mrDYCjlc4o8iD82mk8liyXU5VyjQK1kGhmq4EvLo+YxOEhsunk66amVCh7qxFIiBvT4UH5/MZckqe/3jJzGUy4qrwkHErWyhnQ1Xq7Qe4NiFFojGAsbYwPJl6EMMRnMQAC0cHzYkqldB0IwRfwWOWhfDjeIQc9WDCACsiGNneyTJgG03Q63IzWumEsLh5FhrPgAHL4AAexHlywA1JuW8WILcce2CdHLZJZFFvNSNxAUcYsBtFRBF1hiABlJwABw/JmI+HevhXQh8A/MhKHUC1PS6GQIAAETRb8qESDQhAgSoQTQ8RKlKIA===), the check for `null` goes away.
- When the [enumerator is a value type and doesn't implement `IDisposable`](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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), the `try`/`finally` goes away.

The use of the type returned by `GetEnumerator()` is very important so that value type enumerators are not boxed. All the collections in `System.Collections.Generic` have value type enumerator because calls to its methods are not virtual, resulting in a lot better performance.

Putting all together results in the following code:

```cs
static partial class ExpressionEx
{
    public static Expression ForEach<TSource>(Expression enumerable, Expression loopContent)
    {
        var enumerableType = enumerable.Type;
        var getEnumerator = enumerableType.GetMethod("GetEnumerator");
        if (getEnumerator is null)
            getEnumerator = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TSource)).GetMethod("GetEnumerator");
        var enumeratorType = getEnumerator.ReturnType;
        var enumerator = Expression.Variable(enumeratorType, "enumerator");

        return Expression.Block(new[] { enumerator },
            Expression.Assign(enumerator, Expression.Call(enumerable, getEnumerator)),
            EnumerationLoop(enumerator, loopContent));
    }

    public static Expression ForEach<TSource>(Expression enumerable, ParameterExpression loopVar, Expression loopContent)
    {
        var enumerableType = enumerable.Type;
        var getEnumerator = enumerableType.GetMethod("GetEnumerator");
        if (getEnumerator is null)
            getEnumerator = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TSource)).GetMethod("GetEnumerator");
        var enumeratorType = getEnumerator.ReturnType;
        var enumerator = Expression.Variable(enumeratorType, "enumerator");

        return Expression.Block(new[] { enumerator },
            Expression.Assign(enumerator, Expression.Call(enumerable, getEnumerator)),
            EnumerationLoop(enumerator,
                Expression.Block(new[] { loopVar },
                    Expression.Assign(loopVar, Expression.Property(enumerator, "Current")),
                    loopContent)));
    }

    static Expression EnumerationLoop(ParameterExpression enumerator, Expression loopContent)
    {
        var loop = While(
            Expression.Call(enumerator, typeof(IEnumerator).GetMethod("MoveNext")),
            loopContent);

        var enumeratorType = enumerator.Type;
        if (typeof(IDisposable).IsAssignableFrom(enumeratorType))
            return Using(enumerator, loop);

        if (!enumeratorType.IsValueType)
        {
            var disposable = Expression.Variable(typeof(IDisposable), "disposable");
            return Expression.TryFinally(
                loop,
                Expression.Block(new[] { disposable },
                    Expression.Assign(disposable, Expression.TypeAs(enumerator, typeof(IDisposable))),
                    Expression.IfThen(
                        Expression.NotEqual(disposable, Expression.Constant(null)),
                        Expression.Call(disposable, typeof(IDisposable).GetMethod("Dispose")))));
        }

        return loop;
    }

    public static Expression Using(ParameterExpression variable, Expression content)
    {
        var variableType = variable.Type;

        if (!typeof(IDisposable).IsAssignableFrom(variableType))
            throw new Exception($"'{variableType.FullName}': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'");

        var getMethod = typeof(IDisposable).GetMethod("Dispose");

        if (variableType.IsValueType)
        {
            return Expression.TryFinally(
                content,
                Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(variable, typeof(IDisposable)), getMethod));
        }

        if (variableType.IsInterface)
        {
            return Expression.TryFinally(
                content,
                Expression.IfThen(
                    Expression.NotEqual(variable, Expression.Constant(null)),
                    Expression.Call(variable, getMethod)));
        }

        return Expression.TryFinally(
            content,
            Expression.IfThen(
                Expression.NotEqual(variable, Expression.Constant(null)),
                Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(variable, typeof(IDisposable)), getMethod)));
    }

    public static Expression While(Expression loopCondition, Expression loopContent)
    {
        var breakLabel = Expression.Label();
        return Expression.Loop(
            Expression.IfThenElse(
                loopCondition,
                loopContent,
                Expression.Break(breakLabel)),
            breakLabel);
    }
}
```

The `ForEach` without `loopVar` is useful to enumerate without getting the items. That's the case of `Count()` implementation.

EDIT: An updated and tested version is available in the [NetFabric.Reflection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetFabric.Reflection/) NuGet package. Check its [repository](https://github.com/NetFabric/NetFabric.CodeAnalysis/blob/master/NetFabric.Reflection/Expressions/ExpressionEx.ForEach.cs) for the source code.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly expanded version of [canton7's excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27193081/4247453), taking into account the remarks about disposing the enumerator:

```
public static Expression ForEach(Expression enumerable, ParameterExpression loopVar, Expression loopContent)
{
    var elementType = loopVar.Type;
    var enumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
    var enumeratorType = typeof(IEnumerator<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);

    var enumeratorVar = Expression.Variable(enumeratorType, "enumerator");
    var getEnumeratorCall = Expression.Call(enumerable, enumerableType.GetMethod("GetEnumerator"));
    var enumeratorAssign = Expression.Assign(enumeratorVar, getEnumeratorCall);
    var enumeratorDispose = Expression.Call(enumeratorVar, typeof(IDisposable).GetMethod("Dispose"));

    // The MoveNext method's actually on IEnumerator, not IEnumerator<T>
    var moveNextCall = Expression.Call(enumeratorVar, typeof(IEnumerator).GetMethod("MoveNext"));

    var breakLabel = Expression.Label("LoopBreak");

    var trueConstant = Expression.Constant(true);

    var loop =
        Expression.Loop(
            Expression.IfThenElse(
                Expression.Equal(moveNextCall, trueConstant),
                Expression.Block(
                    new[] { loopVar },
                    Expression.Assign(loopVar, Expression.Property(enumeratorVar, "Current")),
                    loopContent),
                Expression.Break(breakLabel)),
            breakLabel);

    var tryFinally =
        Expression.TryFinally(
            loop,
            enumeratorDispose);

    var body =
        Expression.Block(
            new[] { enumeratorVar },
            enumeratorAssign,
            tryFinally);

    return body;
}
```